# Should I use sapply to run simulations that don't require an argument?

Tags: r, performance, simulation, sapply, processing-efficiency

I am running a simulation thousands of times that does not require any arguments. Here is a very simple example:

```
simulate <- function() sum(sample(1:10, size = 5))
```

I could run

```
results <- rep(0,1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
  results[i] <- simulate()
}
```

...but I've read many times that for loops are slow in R, and I need to maximize speed (the actual simulation I am doing is much more time intensive than this).

1. Should I use a member of the `apply` family on `results` and if so how?
2. Is `sapply` still faster than a for loop if the elements of `results` aren't
   being used in the simulate function?

Comment: If you intialize the result before, as you do here, loops are perfectly fine. See https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` for this but usually for such cases I prefer `replicate`.

```
set.seed(123)
replicate(10, simulate())
#[1] 29 24 27 29 29 19 22 31 28 23
```

You can also use `rerun` in `purrr` which behaves the same way as `replicate`.

---

Using `sapply` the way would be with an anonymous function.

```
sapply(1:10, function(X) simulate())
```